# cmd terminate application after specified time of execution

Tags: cmd, timeout, call, terminate

I installed linphone application and i am writing a bat file doing a loop through file to make calls through executing this command

```
echo call %%H%%Z@%%G^|"C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\linphonec.exe"
```

Now the loop is working fine and everything is ok but the problem that linphone is not terminating after making the first command to move on for the remaining of the loop , when i try to use linphone directly thorough the cmd command it remain open until i use quit command like this

```
C:\Users\administrator>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin

C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin>linphonec -s 111@1.1.1.1
WARNING: no real random source present!
Ready
Warning: video is disabled in linphonec, use -V or -C or -D to enable.
linphonec> Establishing call id to sip:111@1.1.1.1, assigned id 1
Contacting sip:111@1.1.1.1
linphonec> Call 1 to sip:111@1.1.1.1 in progress.

linphonec> quit
Terminating...
Call ended
linphonec> Call 1 with sip:111@1.1.1.1 ended (No error).
No response.
linphonec>

C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin>
```

how i can terminate the program in my command above after executing the call command ?

Answer (score 1):

I have not linphone to test, but if the program accepts piped commands, *maybe*, this could work

```
(echo call %%H%%Z@%%G&echo quit)|"C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\linphonec.exe"
```

**edited** to make it wait

```
(
 echo call %%H%%Z@%%G
 ping -n 11 localhost >nul 2>nul 
 echo quit
) | "C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\linphonec.exe"
```

or

```
(echo call %%H%%Z@%%G& ping -n 11 localhost >nul 2>nul & echo quit)|"C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\linphonec.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks the command done well but it quit the command immediately ; i want to quit command after 10 sec ?

Comment: Thanks the quit command & the time waiting 10 sec done well but when i add it to call command the call request don't send ? i use the Second command [(echo call %%H%%Z@%%G& ping -n 11 localhost >nul 2>nul & echo quit)|"C:\Program Files (x86)\Linphone\bin\linphonec.exe"]